# I keep getting this error and I don't know why (TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given)

Tags: python

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
    def describe_user(self):
        print(f"User information: {self.first_name} {self.last_name}")
    def greet_user(self):
        print(f"Hello {self.first_name} {self.last_name}!")

class Admin:
    def __init__(first_name, last_name):
        super().__init__(self, first_name, last_name)
    def list_privileges(self):
        self.privilege = ["Can add post", "Can ban user", "Can delete post"]
    def show_privileges(self):
        for priv in self.privilege:
            print(priv)

my_user = Admin("John", "Smith")           <--------- (Where I get error)
my_user.show_privileges()
```

Comment: Your `Admin.__init__` definition is missing a `self` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, usually functions from classes and libraries are included with

```
<library name>.<function/attribute>(arguments)
```

where the library name is an argument in itself(where to find the function.)
This means that the arguments are located where the arrows are pointed:

```
<library name>.<function/attribute>(argument 1,argument 2)
       ^                                ^            ^
       |                                |            |
```

However, whenever you call a function such as `__init__`, the function does what it says:
initiate the function. Thus, calling `Admin()` is essentially the same thing as `Admin.__init__`. So, there are three attributes: `first_name`, `last_name`, and `Admin`(the class that __init__comes from.) Admin is included by the modification

```
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
```

However, when you run this, you get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    my_user = Admin("John", "Smith")
  File "main.py", line 15, in __init__
    super().__init__(self, first_name, last_name)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

This error is pretty self-referential - super() is like a class, and the __init__() function only takes one argument-the class name. So, we can delete the `(self, first_name, last_name)` and run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
    my_user.show_privileges()
  File "main.py", line 21, in show_privileges
    for priv in self.privilege:
AttributeError: 'Admin' object has no attribute 'privilege'
```

This means that `self.privileges` isn't defined yet. Because you haven't called the function show_privileges yet, just replace the driver code(outside the class) with

```
my_user = Admin("John", "Smith")    
my_user.list_privileges()
my_user.show_privileges()  
"""
outputs 
Can add post
Can ban user
Can delete post
"""
```

Hope this works!